# Error converting JSON to .Net object in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, json

I am unable to convert JSON string to .net object in asp.net. I am sending JSON string from client to server using hidden field (by keeping the JSON object.Tostring() in hidden field and reading the hidden field value in code behind file)

**Json string/ Object:**

```
 [[{"OfferId":"1","OrderValue":"11","HostingTypeID":"3"},
{"OfferId":"1","OrderValue":"11","HostingTypeID":"3"},
{"OfferId":"1","OrderValue":"11","HostingTypeID":"3"},
{"OfferId":"1","OrderValue":"2","HostingTypeID":"3"},
{"OfferId":"1","OrderValue":"2","HostingTypeID":"3"},
{"OfferId":"1","OrderValue":"67","HostingTypeID":"3"},
{"OfferId":"1","OrderValue":"67","HostingTypeID":"3"}],
[{"OfferId":"1","OrderValue":"99","HostingTypeID":"6"}],
[{"OfferId":"1","OrderValue":"10","HostingTypeID":"8"}]]
```

.Net Object

```
public class JsonFeaturedOffer
{
    public string OfferId { get; set; }

    public string OrderValue { get; set; }

    public string HostingTypeID { get; set; }
}
```

Converstion code in code behind file

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(HdnJsonData.Value);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonFeaturedOffer));
        object result= serializer.ReadObject(stream);
        JsonFeaturedOffer jsonObj = result as JsonFeaturedOffer;
```

While converting i am getting following error:

Expecting element 'root' from namespace ''.. Encountered 'None'  with name '', namespace ''.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Instead of doing this manually I would recommend using the **built in** lightweight [**JavaScriptSerializer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). **No attributes** are required on the classes you want to serialize/deserialize.

It's also more **flexible and faster** than the DataContractJsonSerializer, since it does not have to care about all the wcf stuff. Additionally it has **generic overloads** that make it very simple to use AND it can also handle **anonymous types**.

Serialization:

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var objectAsJsonString = serializer.Serialize(objectToSerialize);
```

Deserialization:

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
JsonFeaturedOffer deserializedObject = serializer.Deserialize<JsonFeaturedOffer>(s_JsonBaseDate);
```

To make it even easier you can create Extension methods that will give you json serialization/deserialization directly on the objects/strings.

Comment: you're wrong on one thing: it is x3-4 times slower from what I see in my tests

Comment: This is an answer from 2010, I sure hope that the standard json serializer has improved :)

Comment: @ntziolis Not really. Even Microsoft recommends using Newtonsoft. The performance of JSON.Net is incredible.

Answer (score 82):

Unfortunately, none of the proposed solutions solve the real source of the problem. This exception means that your deserializer **tries to read from the end of a stream**.

The solution is to rewind the stream to the beginning, ie. set the **`stream.Position = 0;`** before deserialization.

Also, as the comments mention, if you used a StreamWriter you need to flush it before using the stream.

Comment: Same solution for me as well. Thanks.

Comment: Had a similar Issue though in my case it was that the string writer i was using to populate the stream before letting the deserializer at it hadn't flushed to the stream before the deserializer was reading from it

Comment: Or you need to call Flush method before setting the Position on your Writer if your memory stream length is 0

Answer (score 3):

If you want the class to auto-magically serialize into json/xml or deserialize in the object you need to decorate it with some serializable attributes:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("JsonFeaturedOffer"), DataContract(Name="JsonFeaturedOffer")]
public class JsonFeaturedOffer  
{
    [XmlElement ("OfferId"), DataMember(Name="OfferId")]
    public string OfferId {get; set;}
```

... and so on

Answer (score 2):

If this is an array of arrays of JsonFeaturedOffers, shouldn't it be:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(HdnJsonData.Value);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonFeaturedOffer[][]));
object result= serializer.ReadObject(stream);
JsonFeaturedOffer[][] jsonObj = result as JsonFeaturedOffer[][];
```