# Increase performance of an ajax call that get a json string

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json, entity-framework

I am working on an ASP.NET C# application and I am looking to improve the performance of an action.

What I have is a button, when the user clicks it I send an Ajax call to get data from the database and display the data.

The schema of the database is like this:

[image: Database schema]

I have a list of countries, each country has multiple series (Population, Oil, Water....) and each series has multiple years (Each year has a value). So basically its the evolution of a series through the years foreach country.

To Get the data I use AJAX to call a webservice. The webservice take as an input a Series name and I need as an output the data of that series for each coutry for all the years. The output data should be a Javascript object that looks like this:

Water = { "1990": { "USA": 0.1, "Canada": 0.3, "Australia": 0.4 }, "1991": { "USA" : 0.1, "Canada": 0.5 }}

The ajax call:

```
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Service/WebService.asmx/GetData",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                data: "{'Series':'" + Series+ "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    mapValues = JSON.parse(data.d); 
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

The service use Entity framework to read from the database.

```
var Context = new DataModel.DBEntities();
IEnumerable<YearClass> r = (from y in Context.Years
                                          where y.Series.Name == Variable
                                          select new YearClass
                                          {
                                              year = y.Name,
                                              value = y.Value,
                                              CountryCode = y.Series.Country.Code
                                          });
```

yearClass is a strongly typed type just to use it here.

Then I loop through all the years and build the JSON by concatenating a string to match the wanted format.

However this process is talking lots of time and I need to find a way to increase it's performance.

What part can be improved? any tips is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which part of the process is taking "lots of time"? It's not clear from your post?

Comment: I am not sure. When I click the button the application freezes for 4 seconds then I get the data. how can I know which part is talking the most time?

Comment: I would say, that most of performance drop can make indexes: index on Name column, Code. Next it's normal for first request to be very long (as you said 4 sec).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668626/error-converting-json-to-net-object-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Don't generate JSON yourself. Once you've constructed your object graph, which has the right properties on it, return it from your controller action as a [`JsonResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.aspx) using the [`Json()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json.aspx) function. You could also look to use a third-party JSON serialiser such as [JSON.net](http://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json).

Comment: Where You see MVC? WebService.asmx shows that is used traditional old web services.

Comment: Good point. For some reason I missed that. Oh well :) My bad.