# Expecting element 'root' from namespace ''. Encountered 'None' with name '', namespace ''

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm trying to deserialize a simple json object `{"UserID":1","VenueID":14}` 
I have built a class that should take in a serialized json string as follows:

```
public class jsDeserial{
    public T jsDeserialize<T>(string jsStr)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serJs = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(jsStr));
        T obj = (T)serJs.ReadObject(stream);
        stream.Close();
        return obj;
    }
}
```

In the codebehind of my page I have typed the following:

```
[DataContract]
public class VenueUser
{
    [DataMember]
    public int VenueID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

and to initiate de-serialization I have typed

```
    protected int VIdentifier
    {
        get
        {
            jsonStuff.jsDeserial js = new jsonStuff.jsDeserial();
            var vid=js.jsDeserialize<VenueUser>(uD);
            return vid.VenueID;
        }
    }
```

uD represents the serialized json data: {"VenueID":14,"UserID":1}

jsonStuff is just a namespace that contains the VIdentifier property.

Anyhow, I get the following error which I can't figure out:

Expecting element 'root' from namespace ''.. Encountered 'None'  with name '', namespace ''.

Comment: Isn't `Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount()` just getting the number of bytes rather than the data?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6543141/728795) should help. I actually suspect this is a duplicate

Comment: Yeah, that sets the size of the memorystream

Comment: my previous comment is directed at Barry O'Kane's question.

Comment: Thank you Andrei.  I tried decorating the property class as well I have tried setting the "stream.Position=0" before deserializing.  :\  no change.

Comment: Barry O'Kane.  I'm terribly embarrassed.  You were right.  I used the wrong method.  I needed GetBytes not GetByteCount()  Thank you so much for that.