# .exe dependency cannot find .dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to read some proprietary files using a proprietary library. This library comes with a `.exe` file which, sometime in the middle of the process is called. This file, however, throws the error below.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: HarvestCalibration Error: Expecting element 'root' from namespace ''.. Encountered 'None'  with name '', namespace ''.

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'AgLeaderCalibration.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
   at HarvestCalibration.Program.buildTable(CalibrationInput config)
   at HarvestCalibration.Program.Main(String[] args)

   at CNHVoyager2.HarvestCalibration.CalibrationShim.get_config()
   at CNHVoyager2.HarvestCalibration.CalibrationShim.CalculateSampleFlow(UInt16 sensor_force, Double moisture_percent)
   at CNHVoyager2.V2_RecordHarvestSummary.CalculateSampleFlow(UInt16 sensor_force, Double moisture_percent)
   at CNHVoyager2.CNHV2DatasetSample.FillHarvestAttributeCollection()
   at CNHVoyager2.CNHV2DatasetSample.get_AttributeCollection()
   at test.Program.CreateProperties(ICNHV2DatasetSample sample) in C:\Users\Joao\leaf\test\Program.cs:line 84
   at test.Program.Convert(String inputCN1) in C:\Users\Joao\leaf\test\Program.cs:line 61
   at test.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Joao\leaf\test\Program.cs:line 36
```

A quick search shows that `Expecting element 'root' from namespace ''.. Encountered 'None'  with name '', namespace ''` is a problem when reading buffers [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6543141/5092038)]. However, I think that the library is trying to use the `AgLeaderCalibration.dll` behind the scenes, which I have the `.dll`. I've included it in the project in many ways. Referencing, copying it to output directory, etc., to no success.

I do not know C# that much. Maybe this is a very simple problem in the build process? Versioning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show how you're invoking the EXE?

Comment: I am not invoking it directly. The proprietary library does it. I do not know how. I just have the compiled `.dll`

Comment: @meyer1994 have you been able to resolve this issue? I encounter the same problem.

Comment: @EJB unfortunately no. I have made no progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been in contact with CNH support people, and it turns out you need the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 installed: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679. Make sure you get the 32 bit version ( 
VSU_4\vcredist_x86.exe)